# Alternatives to Timestamp in MySql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I recently stumbled across the timestamp problem for my table. I used a timestamp field with "on update current_timestamp" set. When I dumped the table in my local machine, I see that the values of the timestamp field were different. After researching a bit, I found out that the timestamp field depends on the timezone of the server.

My question is Is there a way to use a field with both date and time in it, so that I can know the time when record gets updated. I should be able to dump the same table and have the same data.

My goal is to be able to dual sync the tables.

Comment: You could use DATETIME field...!

Comment: I created a DATETIME field and added triggers for "On Insert" and "On Update". It worked. Thanks Sudhir.