# Alternative to timestamp column for syncing purpose

Tags: mysql, synchronization, timestamp

I have a local mysql db and a production mysql db. I make changes locally and use a third party tool to sync the changes to the live server. The tool uses the checksum feature to identify the rows changed. My db structure is simple, one varchar200 field (acts as primary key), and a text field.

The problem is the sync is taking ages since there are thousands of rows. I believe adding a timestamp field will held in getting the checksum quickly for the tool to identify the rows to be synced. this created further more problems, as the timestamp field is different in local and prod servers due to the timezone differences.

I am looking for a useful idea or an alternative to timestamp that gets changed when a row is modified.

PS: I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589441/alternatives-to-timestamp-in-mysql)  but didn't get any useful answers. I dont wany to rely on additional tables.

Comment: Can your old data change or only new insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My tip: Don't use `TIMESTAMP` datatype, use `DATETIME`. They hold the same kind of data, but difference is `TIMESTAMP` is updated *every time you touch the row*, even if you don't set that column, it will be updated with "now", including insertions.

This means when you use `TIMESTAMP`, you can never truly synch the two databases - that column will always be different. If you use `DATETIME`, you can preserve that column's data.

If you can't code your applications to update the `DATETIME` column with "now", simply create a trigger that will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could do several things:

1. add a column for "dirty" to the source table. Make it a single BIT that you flip when the row gets changed and flip it back when it gets sync'd. If the row id is a primary key this is a simple insert ... on duplicate key update
2. store all your times as GMT. So no more fighting over timezone. This is standard practice anywhere time is being stored anyway.
3. setup replication between the two servers so MySQL will do the copying / updating for you. This is precisely what its designed for and it works well.

Comment: Option 2 seems to nice. But will adding a datetime column help the tool create checksum for the row quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamping the rows is in fact a bad idea, by the time the client updates its own latest syncing time, many rows may get updated on the server and you may miss these. Use a counter which increases by one every time you add or modify rows on the server, the client update itself and get the latest value of the counter. The client may not get the very last value for the counter (e.g. some row get updated while the client is requesting the update) but it's guarantee to catch up at the next update